# Help with Creating Models for Views

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

I am trying to create a Model to pass to a gsp view.  I would like to do a sub query across two tables.  I have two domains, alum_profile and alum_position.  alum_profile has many alum_position's.  alum_position belongs to alum_profile.  In SQL if I wanted to create a result set, I would have something like this:

```
Select count(id), 
 (Select CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
    From alum_profile
    where 
    alum_profile_id =alum_profile.id ) as Person        
 FROM alum_position
 GROUP BY  alum_profile_id
 ORDER BY count(id) DESC
```

How do I do this with HQL and create a model that can be passed to a gsp View.

Thanks for your help
jason
I am using Spring Source, with MySQL and writing in groovy on grails

Comment: Do you have any domain classes for these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read of your question, you want to display a list of the Profile's names, along with how many Positions each Profile has, sorted by the number of positions, desc.

First, you need Models:

```
class AlumProfile {
   String first_name
   String last_name

   def hasMany = [positions: AlumPosition]
};

class AlumPosition {
   String name  // I just added this, no idea what you need in here

   def belongsTo=AlumProfile
};
```

Now you want to create a list of the AlumProfiles sorted by position count.   In your controller, you need:

```
def allByPositionCount = {
   def profiles = AlumProfile.list().sort( [compare: { a,b -> a.positions.size().compareTo( b.positions.size() ) }] as Comparator );
   [ profiles: profiles ]
}
```

This will render the allByPositionCount.gsp with the model containing the "profiles" member that is the list of profiles in the correct order, so something like:

```
<g:each in="${profiles}" var="profile" >
    ${profile.first_name} ${profile.last_name} has ${profiles.positions.size()} positions
</g:each>
```

should render what you want.

Comment: Note, this was all from memory, so please allow for typo's or alternative methods that are more "Groovy".